# dominant-baseline:text-before-edge equivalent dy transformation

Tags: xml, svg, coreldraw

I would like to know if there is any workaround not to use `dominant-baseline:text-before-edge` but achieve the same effect.

If I say place text to x=0 y=0 coordinates I would like that point to be the top left corner of the text's bounding box (green), not the start of the first letters baseline(red):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found an idea here:
http://nelsonslog.wordpress.com/2011/09/12/svgtext-baseline-considered-harmful/

in my case the setting is about:

> dy=".84em"

Answer (score 0):

What is the problem with `dominant-baseline`? The `dy='.84em'` hack unfortunately is dependent on the precise metrics of the font actually being used, which if you're using something like `sans-serif` cannot be predicted accurately. I have used `dominant-baseline: central` together with a `dy='50%'` which works well on all the platforms I have targeted.

One is tempted to use `alignment-baseline`, but support is spotty.

Comment: Unfortunately neither `dominant-baseline` nor `alignment-baseline` are supported by Corel Draw.